# Playing videos from external Camera to Exoplayer without the usage of Streaming(RTMP,RTSP etc)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a situation wherein ,I want to capture video and audio from a external camera and view the media in any container format like *(MP4,FLV,MKV etc)* and play it in ExoPlayer or any ..Is this possible.??
And I am using a **HiMedia Q10 Android Box**..
...It would be really helpful if someone could suggest me with some ideas...!!

Comment: How is external camera connected to Android device? Any info on how or what is transmitted? Those formats require audio/video bytes so is your camera sending bytes? What has the **HiMedia Q10** box got to do with the process of programming your app?

Comment: @VC.One Hi...we need to connect the camera via USB  or either through a "HDMI capture adapter" to the android box if possible...And the **Himedia Box** is used for running an application that gets the feed from the camera..I could not be more specific since we are not sure how the setup can be done..If theres any suggestion on the setup..do kindly post!!

Comment: A quick [search on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=WKXBW7HOLY2_gQbCp7LoBQ&q=android+detect+hdmi+connection) gives: [option one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264579/detect-if-hdmi-is-connected-via-event) and [option two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430835/detect-hdmi-port-in-android-device) amongst others. Make a **basic app** that just shows text confirming that a _"port was detected"_ and also that can detect if something (eg: camera) is connected. Take it from there, like next step is researching how to receive video data via HDMI etc..

Comment: @VC.One..thanks for the suggestions...!! will check how the flow goes.